# Why does webpages_Membership table CreateDate field have wrong datetime?

Tags: sql-server-2012, iis-8

My IIS 8.0.9200.16384 server (and SQL Server 2012) are set for PST (UTC-8) timezone, yet when using the Microsoft Authentication methods the table `Webpages_Membership`'s `CreateDate` field shows UTC+8 values.

In our own `UserProfile` table the datetimes are correct for `LastLogin` (UTC-8). I can understand that CreateDate was simply UTC, but why is it UTC+8? Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel a bit embarrassed, but I found the membership saves datetime.now() as UTC.  My server is configured as PST time zone (UTC - 8). Most of my other dateTime fields are recording local time (probably not a good ideal), so that is why the CreateDate field was 8 hours ahead of me.  I wasn't the one who programmed the site, so I jumped to the wrong conclusion that there was something wrong.